# How to fire flash messages when using Event::on()?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm looking to hook into an `Asset::EVENT_BEFORE_HANDLE_FILE` event and toss up a JS flash error if it's above a certain file size. However, the `registerJs()` function never runs and I assume it's because this is some sort of anti-pattern. What is the more proper way to achieve this sort of thing?

```php
Event::on(
    Asset::class,
    Asset::EVENT_BEFORE_HANDLE_FILE,
    function (Event $event) {
        $asset = $event->asset;

        if (filesize($asset->tempFilePath) > 100000) {
            Craft::$app->getView()->registerJs('Craft.cp.displayError("Example error message")');
        }
    }
);
```